# Gradient Reversal Layer in Keras with Tensor flow backend

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, keras, backpropagation

I saw some code snippets for GRL layer in keras with Theano backend. How can I implement it with a Tensorflow backend. I have less experience with keras. I'm trying to implement DANN (domain adversarial neural network)

Answer (score 2):

see the below link for the gradient reversal layer in tensorflow backend

https://github.com/michetonu/gradient_reversal_keras_tf

Comment: The output of this is a Dense(2) layer and how could I use if to finish a DAN implementation? I'm not an expert with Keras,could you please explain on how the result fits in the network and how to proceed further.